# HTML Forms Text onkeyup

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onkeyup

This code changes whatever the user types in the box to uppercase, and displays the result in the box.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function upperCase(x)
{
   var y=document.getElementById(x).value;
   document.getElementById(x).value=y.toUpperCase();
   document.getElementById("mySpan").value=y.toUpperCase();

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="upperCase(this.id)">
<br/>
<span id="mySpan"></span>

</body> </html>
```

But how can I make it so that it displays it UNDER the text box? And that when the user types, the upper case text is displayed under the text box?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to learn the basics of HTML and Javascript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest the following, more maintainable approach, which uses the [event registration model](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html) as opposed to the [inline model](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html):

JS:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("fname").onkeyup = function() {
    document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML = this.value.toUpperCase();   
}
</script>
```

Markup:

```
Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname"/>
<br/>
<span id="mySpan"></span>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/GPZ8h/

Comment: how would I put a "span" under the box? I'm not familiar with these.

Comment: is a "span" a type of form input?

Comment: this is what I have:Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="upperCase(this.id)">
<span id="mySpan"></span>

Comment: @Robert - not a form element. See the link, or google "html span".

Comment: please see above. that is my current code. how do I make this work?

Comment: @Robert - use `.innerHTML`, not `.value`. See the above.

Comment: @Robert Eisinger - I've completely redone the answer, and included a demo.

Comment: how do I link those pages together? i'm new to html and javascript? can you give me two complete codes and tell me what file name to save it as?

Comment: @Robert Eisinger - Just replace the script you already have with the above JS, and the contents of the body tag with the above markup.

Comment: <html>
<head>
<script>
document.getElementById("fname").onkeyup = function() {
    document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML = this.value.toUpperCase();   
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname"/>
<br/>
<span id="mySpan"></span>


</body> </html>

Comment: @Robert Eisinger - I seriously *doubt* that this is the problem, by try putting a semi-colon after the last curly brace in the JS: `function() { document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML = this.value.toUpperCase(); };`

Comment: that didn't work :( any other ideas? I see that the javascript and the markup work...but how can I combine those into a working file(s)?

Comment: @Robert - do you have a link to your broken page? I really don't understand what the problem could be.

Comment: CURRENT CODE: 
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("fname").onkeyup = function() {
    document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML = this.value.toUpperCase();   
};
</script>

</head>
<body>

Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname"/>
<br/>
<span id="mySpan"></span>


</body> </html>

Comment: @Robert put that script tag under the `</body>` tag and all should work: http://jsbin.com/ezoke4/edit

Comment: @Robert - no worries :) @subhaze - Nice one, sharply spotted :)

Comment: Unless you want the value of the textbox interpreted as HTML, don't use `innerHTML` to populate the span. Create a text node instead: `document.getElementById("mySpan").appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.value.toUpperCase()));`. By all means use `innerHTML` to clear the span's contents first.

Answer (score 2):

Create a css class

```
.showUpperCase { text-format: uppercase; }
```

and add this to your span or textBox.

```
<span id="mySpan" class="showUpperCase"></span>
```

This doesn't change the characters entered, only shows them as upper-case.
That means that if you're handling input via a textBox, you'll have to 
change to upper-case server-side as well.  This is not an additional
chore, since you have to be wary of client-side handling and da a server-side verification, regardless of what the client does